# How to check preconditions on a newly installed server to make sure that a server will actually work

Tags: installation

When installing new servers I usually tend to forget something that is needed for the server actually work. I would like to have some kind of automatic pre-flight check to notice missing features before starting the server for the first time and have live users running on the server.

Let's say I am running a pool of application servers using a platform like Tomcat or PHP behind a load balancer. The service usually requires a few of the following things:

- installed software (external programs like wget or ImageMagick etc)
- installed modules (e.g. libcurl, mod_rewrite, Oracle etc)
- configuration files (e.g. tnsnames, php.ini etc)
- mounted filesystems, symlinks somewhere, specific permissions for some directories
- specific network ports have to be reachable from the machine (e.g. mysql or a http proxy)
- specific network ports have to be reachable on the machine (this would have to be tested from another machine, e.g. rsync or port 8080)
- specific processes have to be started
- cronjobs have to exist

I assume that it would be possible to write unit tests for most of these conditions and run them on each machine after installation, but I would prefer a more specific tool for such a task, maybe with a special shell-like language to write the tests (given that different tools are necessary to test everything, this would involve running perl scripts, java programs, check for files, permissions, lines in confic files etc).

I should add that I do not want to be able to fix the missing items, I just want to check if I have to request additional changes from the operations colleagues.

Comment: Use a configuration management tool.

Comment: Can you please provide an example which? (assuming that I am a complete newbie in this field)

Answer (score 2):

The way we do this is by using CFengine (but Puppet would work just as well) to do configuration of individual nodes based on centralized configuration. CFengine will enforce the correct configuration of the machine in proper order and keep on doing so, e.g. processes will be restarted if they're stopped.

On all nodes a script is available to check a number of things (are files on central storage readable, are weable to open a connection to the MySQL cluster, etc). This script are used by the loadbalancer as a health check: only if all checks pass the node will return the value the loadbalancer expects and will it be flagged as 'up' and allowed to handle traffic.

Comment: I think my question boils down to what do you use for script to check the things

Comment: @AlexLehmann - you use a configuration management system. This is exactly what they excel at: ensuring a system conforms to a certain set of criteria. If you don't ever want to make changes, just run the config management system in "dry run" mode and it will tell you what is missing. Your other alternative is to write a shell script, which could easily do all of this, but you'd be reinventing many wheels in the process...

Comment: @AlexLehmann - check out Ansible. It's a python-based CM system that is quite easy to get started with. It's very approachable, much more so than puppet, chef, cfengine, etc., and it has a very active mailing list and user community.

Comment: The script we use to check is just a PHP or python script we wrote ourselves which does a number of tests: read files from central storage, connect to a database, etc. It returns the output the loadbalancer expects only if all tests succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to document your build process before you can make a script to test the "ready-ness" of your new systems. The process document will give you the check list you want to verify and a consistent build of each server. Cfengine and puppet are great ways to automate builds but to use them you need a list of everything that needs to be configured.

Comment: Yes of course, but assuming I have a list, which tool do I use to check off the items on the list? In a way I do not care how the builds are done (if this is done by another team, however the builds could use the same ruleset).